# For Loop in Jasmine Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

In a service that I have, I am trying to test an array of objects. Something like 
[obj1,obj2,obj3] etc. The test suite is just testing that the object is valid. I have something like

```
beforeEach(() => {
        serviceTest= TestBed.get(service);

        objToBeTested = test.isValid(obj);

    });
```

Then I have a bunch of tests testing that object. I want something like

```
for(var i = 0; i<arrOfObj.length; i++){
beforeEach(() => {
                serviceTest= TestBed.get(service);

                objToBeTested = test.isValid(arrOfObj[i]);

            });

}
```

Where it would iterate through each object and run all the tests for each object. Is that possible?

Comment: It seems you should spend some more time in the Jasmine docs. `beforeEach` is there so that you can run some preparations for each `it` case within a `describe`. You don't actually "do your testing" in a `beforeEach`. You can assign your array of objects into a variable in scope of your `it` case(s), and then execute your tests in those `it` case(s). Within just one of those `it` cases, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to loop through that array of objects and run the tests that you'd like.